# Opening and closing mobile responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm trying to build a mobile responsive "hamburger" menu. The html which I'm using for this is below...

```css
.menu_closed {
  color: red;
}
.menu_open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('span.menu_closed').click(function() {
    $('ul.menu').toggle('1000');
    $(this).toggleClass("menu_open menu_closed");
  });
</script>
<span class="menu_closed">&#9776;</span>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul class='section' id='section_1'>
    <li><span id='section_title_1' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_1'>Against the odds.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_1' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_2' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_3' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_4' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/betting_history'> &rarr; Betting history</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_2'>
    <li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_2'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>black swans</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_5'>
    <li><span id='section_title_5' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_5'>Running faster.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_107' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>possible areas to explore</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_108' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>developing the model</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_109' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>performance</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_4'>
  </ul>
  <div class='bot'>
    <p><a href='https://www.twitter.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">twitter</a>
      <br />
      <a href='https://www.facebook.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">facebook</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

For some reason, it's not closing and opening as it should. I've no idea what's wrong.

I would be grateful if anybody could help.

Jack

Comment: Open up your console and see if there are any errors. Chances are jquery is not being loaded in before your script therefore making your variables undefined.

Comment: You did include jQuery in the code?  It isn't there in the question.

Comment: I've loaded jQuery. I've used it for other things on the page. I'll double check for errors now. Thanks. I haven't included jQuery it in the question. I'll amend it now.

Comment: There are no errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('span.menu_closed').click(function() {` should reference a standard menu class, like `.hamburger`, not `.menu_closed` because if you change `.menu_closed` to `.menu_open` then `.menu_closed` no longer exists and you'll lose the click handler.

`$(this).toggleClass("menu_open menu_closed");` should just toggle a class like `open` or `closed`. Technically what you were doing would work OK where the classname was `.menu_open` and you update this `$.toggleClass()` line to toggle the class `.menu_closed`, but then you end up with an element called `span.menu_open.menu_closed`. Better to name the menu something agnostic, then toggle whether it's open or not.

Also added `cursor: pointer;` to the menu to give an indication to the user that you can click the element.

Wrapped your jQuery code in `$(function() {});` which will cause the page to wait to run the JS until the DOM is ready. This is needed since your JS comes before the rest of the HTML on the page.

And changed your click handler from using `$.live()` (deprecated) to `$.on()`. `$.live()` was [deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/live/), and jQuery advises using `$.on()` now to attach event handlers.

```css
.hamburger {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.open {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.hamburger').on('click',function() {
       $('ul.menu').toggle(1000);
       $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
</script>
<span class="hamburger">&#9776;</span>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
  <ul class='section' id='section_1'>
    <li><span id='section_title_1' class='section_title'><a href='#' id='section_link_1'>Against the odds.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_1' class='exhibit_title'><a href="../against-the-odds/introduction"> &rarr; Introduction</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_2' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/deriving-functions'> &rarr; Deriving functions</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_3' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/exploiting-odds'> &rarr; Exploiting odds</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_4' class='exhibit_title'><a href='../against-the-odds/betting_history'> &rarr; Betting history</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_2'>
    <li><span id='section_title_2' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_2'>Remembering everything.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_104' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>black swans</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_5'>
    <li><span id='section_title_5' class='section_title'><a href='http://themathsproject.co.uk' id='section_link_5'>Running faster.</a></span>
      <ul>
        <li id='exhibit_107' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>possible areas to explore</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_108' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>developing the model</a>
        </li>
        <li id='exhibit_109' class='exhibit_title'><a href='#'>performance</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class='section' id='section_4'>
  </ul>
  <div class='bot'>
    <p><a href='https://www.twitter.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">twitter</a>
      <br />
      <a href='https://www.facebook.com/themathsproject' target="_blank">facebook</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it all except: "And changed your click handler from using $.live() (deprecated) to $.on()". Do you mind quickly explaining this one more time. I've only just started with jQuery & js

Comment: @Jack you're welcome! Updated my answer. `$.live()` was removed from jquery 1.9 and they recommend you use `$.on()` now for event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

```
hey man i tried your code it's working fine here is
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0vnd4ay/